# Connect GitLab-Runner to docker over SSH

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-deployment

I can't connect my GitLab-Runner to a remote docker host.
The runner is tryieng to connect over http.
Log:

```
Preparation failed: error during connect: Get "http://[user-for-docker]%40[IP of docker host]:22/v1.24/info": dial tcp: lookup [user-for-docker]@[IP of docker host]: no such host
```

Note: The GitLab-runner systemuser is setup to connect over ssh over an ssh-key-pair to a remote user in the docker user-group.

config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "[runner hostname]"
  url = "http://[IP of GitLab host]"
  id = 2
  token = "**********"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-06-29T08:59:52Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    host = "ssh://[user-for-docker]@[IP of docker host]:22"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker-testing
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker-testing
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something"

test-job2:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker-testing
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - docker-testing
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

My aim for now is to test the setup of GitLab->Runner->docker where every service has it's own host.